# how can i get product information from barcode scanner device

Tags: vb.net, barcode-scanner

I am developing a project in VB.NET 2008 which contains a module for Stock Management.

I want to add Product Name and Product Price like information.

So I need a barcode scanner for getting this type of inputs (Product Name, Price, etc.)

I am using TVS BS-L101 Platina Lase Barcode Scanner. When I scan, it will only reflect the barcode Serial Number into the Textbox but I want get informations like Name and Price.

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPC codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) are designed to provide product manufacturers a unique way to identify a product in various stores and supermarkets. Each product's UPC code needs to be different so that prices can be rung up properly. All the UPC contains is that unique code and no product specific information.

If you want to get information about a product by just using its UPC code, you would have to gain access to a database or other type of service that would provide this information. Try a Google search for UPC Code Database or something similar.